# jquery input file change event more than once

Tags: jquery, file-upload

For every choice the handler fired 20 or 30 times

```
$('#fileUpload').on('change',function() {
     debugger;
});
```

Comment: Then you've placed the event handler in the wrong place ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one) which triggers only once.

```
$('#fileUpload').one('change',function() {
     debugger;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have registered the same event handler multiple times.

Change your code to

```
console.log('register');
$('#fileUpload').on('change',function() {
     debugger;
});
```

and check your developer console how often your console prints "register".

Next step is to figure out which function calls the code where you register your event handler, and change logic there to call it only once.